# C# "Access to path is denied" netcore linux/raspbian how to get access to write system file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to write to file that controls rpi's gpio and I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException "Access to path is denied".
I'm writing to file like this:

```
File.AppendText(path, "1");
```

Comment: Run your application as a user with the appropriate authority to write to the file at `path`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I do "dotnet run" as user pi wich has permission to do such thing yet the error is still there and for some reason i cant do "sudo dotnet run"

Comment: @luis_laurent please read the title at least

Comment: Could this blog post be what you're encountering? - http://blog.timwheeler.io/universal-windows-project-raspberry-pi-access-denied-to-path-on-the-device/